# Make inherited method to use subclass' variables instead of superclass'

Tags: java, inheritance, architecture

I am working on a project in Java and I decided to use MVC architecture.

I have `Model` class that looks like this:

```
public class Model {
    static String table_name = null;

    // ...

    public static Model create(Map<String, Object> data) {
        // insert `data` into database table `table_name`
    }

    // ...
}
```

I want to have class `User` that extends `Model`, but I don't want to re-implement `create()` in `User`. I just want to change value of `table_name` and want the inherited `create()` to use subclass' `table_name`:

```
public class User extends Model {
    static String table_name = "users";

    // ...
}
```

How can I achieve this?

---

I know a solution where I add `setTableName()` method to `Model`, but that works only if `table_name` is non-static. However, I need it to be static, because I want `create()` to be static so that I can do this: `User.create()`.

Comment: That won't work. Better pass the value into the method as a parameter

Comment: @GurwinderSingh What exactly stops it from being possible?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593258/is-it-possible-to-access-variable-of-subclass-using-object-of-superclass-in-poly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that there is a static method called 'create' on the Model class doesn't mean that there will automatically be a static 'create' method on a User class that extends the Model class - static methods belong to the class, and they're not inherited.  If you implement your own 'create' method on the subclass, there's no relation between that and the 'create' method on the Model class.  It sounds like you want a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).

If you want to stick with an approach similar to what you've done so far, something like this might work.  It keeps the persistence logic in one place, while allowing each model to define its own table name and data mapping.

```
abstract class Model {

    private PersistenceManager persistenceManager = new PersistenceManager();

    abstract String getTableName();
    abstract Model map(Object persistenceResult);

    public void load(Map<String, Object> data) {
        Object persistenceResult = persistenceManager.create(data, getTableName());

        //Set appropriate fields on this class.
        map(persistenceResult);
    }
}

class User extends Model {

    @Override
    String getTableName() {
        return "Users";
    }

    @Override
    Model map(Object persistenceResult) {
        //Mapping logic.
        return null;
    }
}

class PersistenceManager {

    public Object create(Map<String, Object> data, String tableName) {
        //Persistence logic.

        //Return result of DB insert here.
        return null;
    }
}

class ModelFactory {

    public static Model createModel(Class modelClass, Map<String, Object> data) {
        Model model;
        if (modelClass == User.class) {
            model = new User();
        } else {
            //Cater for other models.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid model.");
        }

        model.load(data);

        return model;
    }
}
```

You can then use it as follows.

```
Map<String, Object> userData = new HashMap<>();
userData.put("name", "Bob");

Model user = ModelFactory.createModel(User.class, userData);
```

There is still room for cleanup in the code (like using Generics), but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: For the moment, I think I will stick to what Gurwinder Singh provided. I have only superficial experience with both software architecture and Java. I am trying to build something simple based on my experience with Laravel and PHP. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Parent can't access child's member (and rightfully so). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593258/is-it-possible-to-access-variable-of-subclass-using-object-of-superclass-in-poly)

What you could do is created a protected method to do the task (it accepts the tablename too) and use that instead.

```
public class Model {
    static String table_name = "A";

    public static Model create(Map<String, Object> data) {
        return create(data, table_name);
    }

    protected static Model create(Map<String, Object> data, String table_name) {
        // logic here
    }
}

public class User extends Model {
    static String table_name = "B";

    public static Model create(Map<String, Object> data) {
        return create(data, table_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is possible in Python. See the example in [section 9.6 Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). Are you sure it is not possible to do in Java?

Comment: I am not sure if it is really possible in python (It shouldn't be otherwise it'll mess up the whole inheritence paradigm) but I am quite sure it is not in Java.

Comment: "What I'm trying to do is possible in WATFOR, why isn't it possible in SNOBOL?" (Or vice versa.) That something is possible in a different language is utterly, unavoidably, a priori irrelevant.